# Unable to install entrprise app through iTunes in windows machine

Tags: itunes, applications, windows

As per apple new update in iTunes app install via iTunes option is removed and if you want to install app you need to use `Apple Configurator 2` to install app through system.

But Above Tool is for **MAC user only** what about Windows user how can i distribute my app to windows users?

Any Idea how to install iPA file through windows machine ?

> Note : Due to security reason my company not allowed to use any third
>   party site like Diawi.

Help me to find out way to install my app through windows machine.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

Apple have very quietly [released iTunes 12.6.3](https://www.macrumors.com/2017/10/09/apple-itunes-with-app-store-included/) - compatible with iOS 11 & still containing the App Store.

[Apple KB: Deploy apps in a business environment with iTunes](https://support.apple.com/HT208079)

You need the direct link, it apparently does not appear as an update.
[Mac link.](https://secure-appldnld.apple.com/itunes12/091-33628-20170922-EF8F0FE4-9FEF-11E7-B113-91CF9A97A551/iTunes12.6.3.dmg)
[Windows 32 bit link.](https://secure-appldnld.apple.com/itunes12/091-33627-20170922-EF8CB708-9FEF-11E7-8504-92CF9A97A551/iTunesSetup.exe)
[Windows 64-bit Link.](https://secure-appldnld.apple.com/itunes12/091-33626-20170922-F51D3530-A003-11E7-8324-03D19A97A551/iTunes64Setup.exe)

If you've already been using 12.7 you may have luck importing your 12.7 lib  to a clean 12.6.3 Library, as outlined on MacRumors, but I had no joy.

I ended up restoring a backup of my Library [just the catalog not all the tunes] from a time before i updated to 12.7.